# Bubble Sort Strings

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

This program is for listing 10 students and their marks. Then I want to sort it with Bubble sort. Here the problem occurs. The marks are getting sorted. But the name is still in the same place. After sorting, name stays in same place and marks get moved according to ascending order.

```
public class StudentResult {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String names[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j" };
        int marks[] = { 100, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 32, 80, 90, 10 };
        System.out.println("Students              Marks");
        System.out.println("____________________________");
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
            System.out.println(names[i] + "          -          " + marks[i]);
        bubbleSort(marks, names);
        System.out.println("\n\n\nSorted List\n\n");
        System.out.println("Students              Marks");
        System.out.println("____________________________");
        for(int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++)
            System.out.println(names[i] + "          -          " + marks[i]);
    }

    static void bubbleSort(int[] marks, String[] names) {
        int n = marks.length;
        int m = names.length;
        int temp = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++){
                if(marks[j-1] > marks[j]){
                    //swap elements
                    temp = marks[j-1];
                    marks[j-1] = marks[j];
                    marks[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: write a class ***student*** with the attributes ***name, mark***, pick up a criteria to sort with, use getters....

Comment: Swap names whenever you swap marks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a small change in your bubble sort method as shown below:

```
static void bubbleSort(int[] marks, String[] names) {
    int n = marks.length;
    int m = names.length;
    int temp = 0;
    String temp1 = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {
            if (marks[j - 1] > marks[j]) {
                // swap elements
                temp = marks[j - 1];
                marks[j - 1] = marks[j];
                marks[j] = temp;
                temp1 = names[j - 1];
                names[j - 1] = names[j];
                names[j] = temp1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will give below output of your programme:

```
Students       Marks
______________________
a        -      100
b        -       20
c        -       30
d        -       40
e        -       50
f        -       60
g        -       32
h        -       80
i        -       90
j        -       10



Sorted List

Students       Marks
______________________
j        -       10
b        -       20
c        -       30
g        -       32
d        -       40
e        -       50
f        -       60
h        -       80
i        -       90
a        -      100
```